# Как реализовать в Rxjava2 обратный отсчет?

Tags: java, android, rxjava

```
Observable.range(10, 0)//revers
.map()...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Observable.range(0, 10)
            .map( value -> 10 - value)
            .takeUntil(value -> value == 0)
            .subscribe(value -> {
                Log.e("TAG =====  ", String.valueOf(value));
            });
```

Comment: оператор takeUntil тут лишний